# Published WPF application exception

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I can run my published WPF application file locally fine, however if I install  to another machine I get a Windows report error dialog. The only useful error info I see is `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`.

I've included all the necessary assembly used in the project, plus the 3rd party assemblies (syncfusion) also included in the GAC of that machine.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: What that's saying is it didn't manage to build the wpf object tree. Crash... That could be because of something in the XAML or the constructor of whichever window it's failing on. Or possibly the app startup. Only you know what is going on there.

Comment: @Andy thank you, I totally ran out of options, I'll look into this one

Comment: Did you look in the machine's windows log?  If it's ctor crash then you may find nothing more of use but it might be worth a go. Once you track this down you might want to consider moving stuff out of constructors if you have code in em and adding global error handling.

Comment: @Andy come to think of it,   ctor crash might be the issue.. totally ignored that part

Comment: Common mistake. Putting all your database reads or setup in the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

The reported xaml parse exception in the machines other than the local machine may due to the resource files not being included along with the deployed files while publishing the application. So please ensure that the necessary resource files needed for the application are marked as “Include” in the Publish Status like in the below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acJAe.png)

Please check and let us know if it is helpful.

Regards,
Gokul S

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues in published WPF .NET Core 3.1 VS 2019.

To me the solution was disabling *Trim unused assemblies (in preview)*:

[image]